# How to do a nested ternary in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two variables, search and selectedAsset. When Search or selectedAsset is shown I would like to set a new variable named optionalparamaters which excutes when search is true or selectedAsset is true. I am trying to pass the optioinalParamaters variable into the url param depending on its case.

```
let optionalSearch =  search === '' ? '' :  `?asset_type=${search}` 

  let optionalSelectedAsset = selectedAsset === '' ? '' : `?asset_type=${selectedAsset}`


     let results = await verifiedGet(`get_all_reviews/${(currentPage - 1) * resPerPage}/${resPerPage}${optionalSearch}`,  user.user)
```

Right now obviously you can see that the optionalSearch is only being called, hence why I wanted to create that new variable optionalParamaters which I can pass through based on whether the condition is sett to search or selectedAsset.

Updated code:

```
let optionalParams = search === '' ? '' :  `?asset_type=${search}`  : (selectedAsset === '' ? '' :  `?asset_type=${selectedAsset}` )
```

Comment: This way: `condition1 ? option1 : (condition2 ? option2 : option3)`

Comment: Yes, the way @PrathameshKoshti showed you should work. But you should really consider using the full syntax if using multiple ternary operators. Because if you use a lot of them, it is quite hard to read and understand your code if a different developer takes a look at it.

Comment: @NielsBosman I agree, you can go with the nested one but readability is important!

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti I did it, but it gave me a synax error, could you please help?

Comment: Okay, I need more info on this. Can you tell me one thing that the variables `search` and `selectedAsset` both are required or only one of them is needed, and also what is expected when both variables have values?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution very readable without ternary.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('resPerPage', resPerPage);
if ( !!search ) {
  params.set('asset_type', search);
  params.set('optionalSearch', true);
}
if ( !!selectedAsset ) {
  params.set('asset_type', selectedAsset);
  params.set('optionalSearch', true);
}

const url = `/${(currentPage - 1) * resPerPage}/?${params.toString()`;
let results = await verifiedGet(url,  user.user);
```

Comment: I agree with farvilain, you should not make ternary conditions complicated, their only goals it's to be a quick condition. If you need to think twice before understand what's going on on your ternary, you should make a function.